# Setting tokenised IPv6 identifiers with libvirt network config

Tags: networking, token, ipv6, kvm, libvirt

I'd like to set user provided lower 64 bits tacked onto the existing /64 prefix with libvirt but I cannot find a way to do this. Is it even possible ? If not, it would be great to add this functionality.

I tried "token" setting in libvirt network config such as :

```
<ip family='ipv6' token='::f33d:100'>
</ip>
```

but it's not recognized.

Thx for the help.

EM

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I found the solution. I'll answer to myself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wronggly assuming I had to set this in libvirt but I finally found what I was looking for. I created a bridge on the host and then managed to set my tokenized IPv6 identifier (for example `::f33d:100`) in the guest network config.

So, now my router advertises the `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd` prefix and my guest IPv6 address is automatically set to `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:dddd::f33d:100`. If ever I decide to use another of my ISP delegated prefix on this network, I just have to reconfigure my router with, for instance, the new `aaaa:bbbb:cccc:eeee` prefix and my guest IPv6 address will automagically switch to `aaaa:bbbb:bbbb:eeee::f33d:100`.